# Basic Authentication CODE 401 Issue

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, basic-authentication

I've some problem with Basic Auth.

Server return me code 401 and i don't understand what is wrong in my code.

I have:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.external_site.it/Login.do");

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+Base64.encodeBase64String((username+":"+password).getBytes()));
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

System.out.println("\nRESPONSE CODE:\t\t" + connection.getResponseCode());
System.out.println("RESPONSE MESSAGE:\t" + connection.getResponseMessage());
```

I compared the base64 string with the one I have in the header and it is equal.

Comment: Shouldn't you use javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: Could you try this:

`Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});`

You should remove the existing authentication code before trying this.

Comment: i've just tried this, but i get always the same 401 code Unauthorized. :( why?

Comment: You say you get 401, but do you get any additional info?

Comment: no additional information. If I visit in my browser https://username:password @ www.external_site.com / Login.do come logged.

I tried to sniff the traffic data at login and I can see the header of the basic authentication with my credentials in base64.

Comment: Can you get access to the server logs? If not, you could try against some other public web server using basic auth, and see if that work. Or set up a dummy web server with basic auth, then see the logs for your program vs. successfully using regular browser.